Not able to activate virtual environment using python 3.12.0 in vs code
I'm working on webapp using python, django and html, css. For that I need to create a virtual environment for that i installed Python 3.12.0 and i run this command "py -m venv myenv" in powershell terminal in vs code. Then the virtual environment created successfully and then I tried to activate the "myenv" and for that i run this command: ".\myenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1" but this giving me error:
.\env\Scripts\Activate : The term '.\env\Scripts\Activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\env\Scripts\Activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\env\Scripts\Activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I also know that there is no file or module with the name "Activate". In the past I created venv in vs code that time every thing worked perfectly but now not working. I also says that I tried to use AI and for that I installed Python 3.8.0 and after that all of this happening. I just need to solution that can create venv.

Two things

You say you ran .\myenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1, but your error message is for .\env\Scripts\Activate.ps1
Command line is Case-sensitive. It isn't .\myenv\Scripts\Activate, it's .\myenv\Scripts\activate (not a capital A)


you are right but the main thing is in scripts folder there is not such file with the name Activate and i don't why it does not appear when venv is created !

Again the name is not Activate it's activate. It is case sensitive.

PS C:\Users\kjpat\OneDrive\Desktop\Quiz App> ..venv\Scripts\activate
..venv\Scripts\activate : The term '..venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

..venv\Scripts\activate

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\.venv\Scripts\activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException





what is the result of dir  .\.venv\Scripts ?

Issue has solved, and the main problem is that I didn't find the "activate.bat" file in "Scripts" folder but when i run vs code as Administrator and then I created venv, after that I can find the activate file.
